# Angular 7 reload current html page with different child component

Tags: angular

I have a `HomeComponent` which has

- A header
- Bootstrap nav-item for tabs
- Series of other selectors [say based on navigation tab clicked i wish to load the specific component]

I have studied how to app child component to existing component. But how can i switch the selector based on click. I do not wish to reload entire page.
My Code is as follow for component:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row min-vh-100 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
      <app-profile></app-profile>
      <app-trending></app-trending>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <ul class="nav nav-fill">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link active">Tweets</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" >Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="mt-5">
        <app-tweets [hidden]="isTweets()"></app-tweets>
        <app-login [hidden]="isFollowers()"></app-login>
        <app-register [hidden]="isFollowing()"></app-register>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-body">This is a footer</div>
```

Worked: `HomeComponent`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HomeTabsState} from './HomeTabsState';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  currentTabState: HomeTabsState;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentTabState = HomeTabsState.Tweets;
  }

  getTwitter(): HomeTabsState {
    return HomeTabsState.Tweets;
  }

  getFollower(): HomeTabsState {
    return HomeTabsState.Followers;
  }

  getFollowing(): HomeTabsState {
    return HomeTabsState.Following;
  }

  getLikes(): HomeTabsState {
    return HomeTabsState.Likes;
  }

  UpdateHome(state: HomeTabsState) {
    this.currentTabState = state;
    console.log("new state " + state);
  }


}
```

Html:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row min-vh-100 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
      <app-profile></app-profile>
      <app-trending></app-trending>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <ul class="nav nav-fill">
        <li class="nav-item " (click)="UpdateHome(getTwitter())">
          <a class="nav-link active">Tweets</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" (click)="UpdateHome(getFollower())">
          <a class="nav-link" >Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" (click)="UpdateHome(getFollowing())">
          <a class="nav-link">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="mt-5">
       <div  *ngIf="currentTabState.valueOf() === getTwitter().valueOf()">
         <app-tweets></app-tweets>
       </div>

        <div  *ngIf="currentTabState.valueOf() === getFollower().valueOf()">
          <app-login></app-login>
        </div>

        <div  *ngIf="currentTabState.valueOf() === getFollowing().valueOf()">
          <app-register></app-register>
        </div>

        <div  *ngIf="currentTabState.valueOf() === getLikes().valueOf()">
          <app-likes></app-likes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-body">This is a footer</div>
```

**But i have a doubt that is this the actual approach or a better once exists?**

Comment: Create a kinda toggler function with corresponding indicator and use *ngIf to show only one you need at the time

Comment: Well it actually worked thanks.